# SQL unknown column in 'WHERE' clause even though column is inserted

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, mysql-workbench

I made sure I'm using single quotes instead of double quotes, but for some reason it's saying that the gender column is unknown.

I've tried changing the 'AND' statement to lowercase, I've tried using various quotations and I've also fixed the order in which the values were set up in the table contents and values.

```
CREATE DATABASE MYSQLEXERCISE5;
USE MYSQLEXERCISE5;
CREATE TABLE myemployees (
gender VARCHAR(255),
first_name VARCHAR(255),
last_name VARCHAR(255),
birth_place VARCHAR(255),
citizen_ship VARCHAR(255),
yearly_wage INT(7) NOT NULL,
age INT(3) NOT NULL,
hours_worked INT(5) NOT NULL,
years_employed INT(6) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO myemployees (gender, first_name, last_name, birth_place, citizen_ship, yearly_wage, age, hours_worked, years_employed)
VALUES ('M', 'Filip', 'Lazarevic', 'Montenegro', 'Australia', 30000, 19, 8000, 4);
INSERT INTO myemployees (gender, first_name, last_name, birth_place, citizen_ship, yearly_wage, age, hours_worked, years_employed)
VALUES ('M', 'Daniel', 'Craig', 'USA', 'England', 75000, 37, 26000, 13);
INSERT INTO myemployees (gender, first_name, last_name, birth_place, citizen_ship, yearly_wage, age, hours_worked, years_employed)
VALUES ('M', 'John', 'Jovovich', 'Serbia', 'USA', 55000, 27, 8000, 4);
INSERT INTO myemployees (gender, first_name, last_name, birth_place, citizen_ship, yearly_wage, age, hours_worked, years_employed)
VALUES ('M', 'Stefan', 'Stojic', 'Croatia', 'Croatia', 'Spain', 100000, 24, 12000, 6);
INSERT INTO myemployees (gender, first_name, last_name, birth_place, citizen_ship, yearly_wage, age, hours_worked, years_employed)
VALUES ('M', 'David', 'Longbottom', 'Ireland', 'UK', 67000, 43, 10000, 5);
INSERT INTO myemployees (gender, first_name, last_name, birth_place, citizen_ship, yearly_wage, age, hours_worked, years_employed)
VALUES ('M', 'Riley', 'Reynolds', 'Canada', 'Canada', 90000, 30, 20000, 10);
INSERT INTO myemployees (gender, first_name, last_name, birth_place, citizen_ship, yearly_wage, age, hours_worked, years_employed)
VALUES ('F', 'Riley', 'Raymond', 'Iceland', 'Greenland', 22000, 19, 6000, 3);
INSERT INTO myemployees (gender, first_name, last_name, birth_place, citizen_ship, yearly_wage, age, hours_worked, years_employed)
VALUES ('M', 'Jade', 'Michaels', 'Egypt', 'France', 100000, 55, 30000, 15);
INSERT INTO myemployees (gender, first_name, last_name, birth_place, citizen_ship, yearly_wage, age, hours_worked, years_employed)
VALUES ('F', 'Jade', 'Smith', 'Syria', 'India', 10000, 50, 10000, 5);
INSERT INTO myemployees (gender, first_name, last_name, birth_place, citizen_ship, yearly_wage, age, hours_worked, years_employed)
VALUES ('M', 'Sam', 'Wilson', 'Scotland', 'Ireland', 34000, 25, 4000, 2);
INSERT INTO myemployees (gender, first_name, last_name, birth_place, citizen_ship, yearly_wage, age, hours_worked, years_employed)
VALUES ('F', 'Sam', 'Wade', 'Russia', 'Finland', 55000, 32, 8000, 4);

SELECT * FROM myemployees WHERE first_name = 'Sam' AND gender = 'M';
SELECT * FROM myemployees WHERE first_name = 'Jade' AND gender = 'F';
```

I want it to show people called Sam whose gender is M and people called Jade whose gender is F

Comment: What's your dbms? mysql or mssql?

Comment: VARCHAR(255) for gender column??

Comment: Also, whilst firstname is a type of name and birthplace is a type of place, citizenship is *not* a type of ship.

Comment: You must provide the same number of values as columns specified in the insert clause. Either insert nulls(if your table permits) or default values to make up to the number of columns required or change the number of columns to be inserted to the number of values required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `or`

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE myemployees (
gender VARCHAR(255),
first_name VARCHAR(255),
last_name VARCHAR(255),
birth_place VARCHAR(255),
citizen_ship VARCHAR(255),
yearly_wage INT(7) NOT NULL,
age INT(3) NOT NULL,
hours_worked INT(5) NOT NULL,
years_employed INT(6) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO myemployees (gender, first_name, last_name, birth_place, citizen_ship, yearly_wage, age, hours_worked, years_employed)
VALUES ('M', 'Filip', 'Lazarevic', 'Montenegro', 'Australia', 30000, 19, 8000, 4);
INSERT INTO myemployees (gender, first_name, last_name, birth_place, citizen_ship, yearly_wage, age, hours_worked, years_employed)
VALUES ('M', 'Daniel', 'Craig', 'USA', 'England', 75000, 37, 26000, 13);
INSERT INTO myemployees (gender, first_name, last_name, birth_place, citizen_ship, yearly_wage, age, hours_worked, years_employed)
VALUES ('M', 'John', 'Jovovich', 'Serbia', 'USA', 55000, 27, 8000, 4);

INSERT INTO myemployees (gender, first_name, last_name, birth_place, citizen_ship, yearly_wage, age, hours_worked, years_employed)
VALUES ('M', 'David', 'Longbottom', 'Ireland', 'UK', 67000, 43, 10000, 5);
INSERT INTO myemployees (gender, first_name, last_name, birth_place, citizen_ship, yearly_wage, age, hours_worked, years_employed)
VALUES ('M', 'Riley', 'Reynolds', 'Canada', 'Canada', 90000, 30, 20000, 10);
INSERT INTO myemployees (gender, first_name, last_name, birth_place, citizen_ship, yearly_wage, age, hours_worked, years_employed)
VALUES ('F', 'Riley', 'Raymond', 'Iceland', 'Greenland', 22000, 19, 6000, 3);
INSERT INTO myemployees (gender, first_name, last_name, birth_place, citizen_ship, yearly_wage, age, hours_worked, years_employed)
VALUES ('M', 'Jade', 'Michaels', 'Egypt', 'France', 100000, 55, 30000, 15);
INSERT INTO myemployees (gender, first_name, last_name, birth_place, citizen_ship, yearly_wage, age, hours_worked, years_employed)
VALUES ('F', 'Jade', 'Smith', 'Syria', 'India', 10000, 50, 10000, 5);
INSERT INTO myemployees (gender, first_name, last_name, birth_place, citizen_ship, yearly_wage, age, hours_worked, years_employed)
VALUES ('M', 'Sam', 'Wilson', 'Scotland', 'Ireland', 34000, 25, 4000, 2);
INSERT INTO myemployees (gender, first_name, last_name, birth_place, citizen_ship, yearly_wage, age, hours_worked, years_employed)
VALUES ('F', 'Sam', 'Wade', 'Russia', 'Finland', 55000, 32, 8000, 4);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * 
FROM myemployees 
WHERE (first_name = 'Sam' AND gender = 'M') or (first_name = 'Jade' AND gender = 'F');

| gender | first_name | last_name | birth_place | citizen_ship | yearly_wage | age | hours_worked | years_employed |
| ------ | ---------- | --------- | ----------- | ------------ | ----------- | --- | ------------ | -------------- |
| F      | Jade       | Smith     | Syria       | India        | 10000       | 50  | 10000        | 5              |
| M      | Sam        | Wilson    | Scotland    | Ireland      | 34000       | 25  | 4000         | 2              |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bAeuW8FkHcwH742cNrN2qo/0)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using IN

```
SELECT * 
FROM myemployees 
WHERE 
   first_name in ('Sam','Jade') AND gender in ('M' , 'F')
```

Answer (score 0):

you did wrong  for this column data insertion that's why you got that error

```
INSERT INTO myemployees (gender, first_name, last_name, birth_place, citizen_ship, 
yearly_wage, age, hours_worked, years_employed)
VALUES ('M', 'Stefan', 'Stojic', 'Croatia', 'Spain', 100000,24, 24,  6);
```

in this row you provided 10 column values but it should be 9
otherwise your both query is working fine

```
SELECT * FROM myemployees WHERE first_name = 'Sam' AND gender = 'M';
```

output

```
gender  first_name  last_name   birth_place     citizen_ship    yearly_wage     age     hours_worked    years_employed
M   Sam     Wilson  Scotland    Ireland     34000   25  4000    2

SELECT * FROM myemployees WHERE first_name = 'Jade' AND gender = 'F';
```

output

```
gender  first_name  last_name   birth_place     citizen_ship    yearly_wage     age     hours_worked    years_employed
F   Jade    Smith   Syria   India   10000   50  10000   5
```

[here is the demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=445b8c153465d2b313220280cb5c26a3)

you could merge them by using `union all`

```
SELECT * FROM myemployees WHERE first_name = 'Sam' AND gender = 'M'
union all
SELECT * FROM myemployees WHERE first_name = 'Jade' AND gender = 'F'
```

instead `unoin all` you can use `in` that shows @fa06 or you can use `OR` that shows @D-shish

Answer (score 0):

**First Drop Your Table From Data Base And Then Run This Query**

```
`CREATE TABLE myemployees (
gender VARCHAR(255),
first_name VARCHAR(255),
last_name VARCHAR(255),
birth_place VARCHAR(255),
citizen_ship VARCHAR(255),
yearly_wage INT NOT NULL,
age INT NOT NULL,
hours_worked INT NOT NULL,
years_employed INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO myemployees (gender, first_name, last_name, birth_place, 
citizen_ship, yearly_wage, age, hours_worked, years_employed)
VALUES ('M', 'Filip', 'Lazarevic', 'Montenegro', 'Australia', 30000, 19, 
8000, 
4);
INSERT INTO myemployees (gender, first_name, last_name, birth_place, 
citizen_ship, yearly_wage, age, hours_worked, years_employed)
VALUES ('M', 'Daniel', 'Craig', 'USA', 'England', 75000, 37, 26000, 13);
INSERT INTO myemployees (gender, first_name, last_name, birth_place, 
citizen_ship, yearly_wage, age, hours_worked, years_employed)
VALUES ('M', 'John', 'Jovovich', 'Serbia', 'USA', 55000, 27, 8000, 4);
INSERT INTO myemployees (gender, first_name, last_name, birth_place, 
citizen_ship, yearly_wage, age, hours_worked, years_employed)
VALUES ('M', 'Stefan', 'Stojic', 'Croatia','Spain', 100000, 24, 12000, 6);
INSERT INTO myemployees (gender, first_name, last_name, birth_place, 
citizen_ship, yearly_wage, age, hours_worked, years_employed)
VALUES ('M', 'David', 'Longbottom', 'Ireland', 'UK', 67000, 43, 10000, 5);
INSERT INTO myemployees (gender, first_name, last_name, birth_place, 
citizen_ship, yearly_wage, age, hours_worked, years_employed)
VALUES ('M', 'Riley', 'Reynolds', 'Canada', 'Canada', 90000, 30, 20000, 10);
INSERT INTO myemployees (gender, first_name, last_name, birth_place, 
citizen_ship, yearly_wage, age, hours_worked, years_employed)
VALUES ('F', 'Riley', 'Raymond', 'Iceland', 'Greenland', 22000, 19, 6000, 3);
INSERT INTO myemployees (gender, first_name, last_name, birth_place, 
citizen_ship, yearly_wage, age, hours_worked, years_employed)
VALUES ('M', 'Jade', 'Michaels', 'Egypt', 'France', 100000, 55, 30000, 15);
INSERT INTO myemployees (gender, first_name, last_name, birth_place, 
citizen_ship, yearly_wage, age, hours_worked, years_employed)
VALUES ('F', 'Jade', 'Smith', 'Syria', 'India', 10000, 50, 10000, 5);
INSERT INTO myemployees (gender, first_name, last_name, birth_place, 
citizen_ship, yearly_wage, age, hours_worked, years_employed)
VALUES ('M', 'Sam', 'Wilson', 'Scotland', 'Ireland', 34000, 25, 4000, 2);
INSERT INTO myemployees (gender, first_name, last_name, birth_place, 
citizen_ship, yearly_wage, age, hours_worked, years_employed)
VALUES ('F', 'Sam', 'Wade', 'Russia', 'Finland', 55000, 32, 8000, 4);`
```

I hope It Will Help You.
[See This Is Causing Error For You](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FObJ3.jpg)